# Avoiding nested for loops when multiplying vectors in Python

Tags: python, numpy, cartesian-product

I am working with a list vectors A and B. Each vector has dimension n, but the size of A and B are different. For each vector in A, I would like to compute its product with all the vectors in B. Here is an example with n=2:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(10,2)
B = np.random.rand(5,2)

for a in A:
    PRODUCT = 1
    for b in B:
        PRODUCT = PRODUCT * np.matmul(a, b)
```

This does what I want, but I was wondering if there are faster methods that avoid using nested for-loops. One idea I had was to use cartesian products by using `from itertools import product`, and then somehow doing these computations every `i % len(B) == 0` iterations. But I was not able to make that work.

Are there ways for improvements? Or nested for loops are the way to go?

Comment: `ab = np.matmul(A, B.T)` produces a (10,5) array.  does `np.prod(ab, axis=1)` produce the (10,) array you want?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a cleaner way to do this, but it works

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
A = np.random.rand(10,2)
B = np.random.rand(5,2)
one = []
two = []
curr = A[0]
PRODUCT = 1

for a, b in product(A, B):
    if np.array_equal(a, curr) is False:
        curr = a
        PRODUCT = 1
        
    PRODUCT = PRODUCT * np.matmul(a, b)
    one.append(PRODUCT)
    

for a in A:
    PRODUCT = 1
    for b in B:
        PRODUCT = PRODUCT * np.matmul(a, b)
        two.append(PRODUCT)

if one == two:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Results

```
True
```